# How limit works when there is two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO Votes (id_post,id_user)
SELECT ?,?
    FROM Posts p, Users u
  WHERE p.id_user = :author_id
         AND u.id = $_SESSION['id']
         AND u.active = 1
  limit 1;
```

As you see, there is two tables `Posts`, `Users`. Now I want to know, that `limit 1` limits the result of which table? In general how it works?

Comment: Use `JOIN` instead of old, comma-separated syntax.

Comment: in anyway the limit is appled to the select result

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas What's wrong with `,` comma-separator? Also I don't know should I use `LEFT` or `INNER` join in that case.

Comment: Implicit comma separated join is the same as modern inner join.

Comment: @jarlh Ok, but look, there isn't any identical column between those two tables. So I cannot write a condition on the `ON` clause. Because there isn't any true condition. So how can I use `JOIN` instead of `,` ?

Comment: Why do you have two different, unrelated tables in one select? (cross join is an inner join without any ON clause.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LIMIT` works on the *results* of the query, not on the individual tables.

You should learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  I imagine it is something like this:

```
SELECT ?, ?
FROM Posts p JOIN
     Users u
     ON p.id_user = u.id
WHERE p.id_user = :author_id AND
      u.id = $_SESSION['id'] AND
      u.active = 1
LIMIT 1;
```

Having said that, `SELECT ?, ?` doesn't really make sense.  You can only insert *constants* as parameters.  You should probably have explicit column names, perhaps:

```
SELECT p.id, u.id
FROM Posts p JOIN
     Users u
     ON p.id_user = u.id
WHERE p.id_user = :author_id AND
      u.id = $_SESSION['id'] AND
      u.active = 1
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: too late... I'll just add that `LIMIT` affects `SELECT`'s output, with no concern for what you select from.